# How to Attach Doc/Word file as attachment using Google appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to GAS, Can anyone please tell me how to send Google Doc File as an attachment using appscript. I know how to send as PDF but I need the Doc File to get attached as Word File from Google Drive.

What I am trying to do is fill a template doc file with data from google sheet with onEdit trigger and attach the new file as a document attachment.

```
function davitFill(e) {

 if (e.range.columnStart != 19 || e.value != "Yes") return;
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEEEiLfil1qfetSwZRhr02Q9uoXvWtCxq22JywTu5mo/edit#gid=1554622983").getSheetByName("TDataBase");
 const rData = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,19).getValues();
 var fname = rData[0][1];
 var add = rData[0][3];
 var dist = rData[0][4];
 var state = rData[0][5];
 var pc = rData[0][6];
 var brand = rData[0][10];
 var cal = rData[0][16];
 var email = rData[0][2];

 var tfile = 
 DriveApp.getFileById("1xMWm2CBA2vLkf5GzFQnHRViLVoJZdbebazUgp0OipV4");
 var savefol = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RzjCSdKU9lwxdonGPBPpIob4KVZ2z80-R");
 var tfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MgmGTCf-_RYBZOHloIYJP_9C68kF67I9H");

 const tempFile = tfile.makeCopy("davit for "+fname, folder);
 const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
 const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{{Full name}}", fname);
  body.replaceText("{{Brand}}", brand);
  body.replaceText("{{Address}}", add);
  body.replaceText("{{Dist}}", dist);
  body.replaceText("{{Class}}", cal);
  body.replaceText("{{State}}", state);
  body.replaceText("{{pc}}", pc);
  var ffile = tempDocFile.saveAndClose();


  var url = tempDocFile.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD];
  var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
  }
  }).getBlob().setName(docFile.title+'.docx');

  MailApp.sendEmail('email', 'WORD ATTACHMENT', 'Test', {attachments: blob});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**For WORD document:**

```
  var docFile = Drive.Files.get('file id');
  var url = docFile.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD];
  var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
    }
  }).getBlob().setName(docFile.title+'.docx');

  MailApp.sendEmail('email', 'WORD ATTACHMENT', 'Test', {attachments: blob});
```

- We use [Advanced Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to get the export link for a word document in `var url = docFile.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD];`.
- We get the blob using the url link and rename the file using `UrlFetchApp.fetch().getBlob().setName()`

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

---

### **Your code should be:**

```
  var newDocFile = Drive.Files.get(tempFile.getId());
  var url = newDocFile.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD];
  var oauthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
  }
  }).getBlob().setName(newDocFile.title+'.docx');

  MailApp.sendEmail('email', 'WORD ATTACHMENT', 'Test', {attachments: blob});
```

Since you created a new file and modified its content, we just need to get the updated document using [Drive.Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?hl=en) using its file id. It should return a [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files?hl=en) which includes `exportLinks`.

---

**Note:**

You need to [enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) before you could use the [Advanced Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

If you are using the new editor:

1. Open the Apps Script project.
2. At the left, click Editor code.
3. At the left, next to Services, click Add a service add.
4. Select an Drive API and click Add.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Tried it but failed...Can u please tell me what am I doing wrong:

Comment: You are using `tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());`  in `var url = tempDocFile.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD];`. As mentioned in the answer you need to use **Advance Drive API** to get the file using `Drive.Files.get('file id');`.It will return a [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) which includes an export link

Comment: I modified your code and added the necessary steps, please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.. Appreciate your Help

Answer (score 0):

contentType

String

The MIME type to convert to. For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.